# Wine fails with DirectX on Pinguy

Tags: xorg, wine, opengl

I am trying to use Wine to play a 3d game on Linux that will run as long as the base system has the correct Direct X rendering. I have tried the Wine configurations and come up with:
http:/(s19.postimage.org/lgv1ky8dv/Selection_002.jpg)

```
$# wine ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/dxdiag.exe
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
Serial number of failed request:  145
Current serial number in output stream:  145
```

The error may be related to the Wine configuration but I followed [the guide](http://www.wine-reviews.net/wine-reviews/microsoft/directx-90c-march-2008-redistributable-on-linux-with-wine.html) (with ver jun2010) to the T on this and I just can't seem to get this to work on my Pinguy (Ubuntu 12.04 kernel: 3.2.0-25-generic-pae) system.

I believe it is a bug within the X.org. I do not have an `/etc/x11/xorg.conf` and my system graphics settings does not show (as other bug reports have said also). I still don't understand how I can fix this.

I have tried AMD installs (in case my processor has a hybrid). I have tried to see if I could compile a new driver (unsuccessful).

I believe it is the stock drivers (MESA Intel sandybridge) but it should be (Intel HD 3000) also I have found that there is a bug reported for xorg or mesa (both are listed as causes) where it does not show up on the system tools and does not play well, both are my symptoms, yet installing mesa-tools does not solve it

[My complete computer specs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03138569&cc=ad&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0002)

Comment: This looks like a Wine bug rather than an X.org bug. Or possibly a graphics driver bug, but Wine is not very reliable. Please post your complete Wine configuration and tell us exactly what graphics driver you're using (proprietary or open source? what version?).

Comment: if you were to research the bugs within xorg / mesa then you would quickly find what i did that specified this exact problem. but there is no fix to it. It is stated that basically (x.org is irrelevent to the problem) it is effective for 2d rendering (or OpenGL to be specific) only.